# How to calculate Internal Rate of Return (IRR)?

Tags: vb.net

I've modified my original question....

I have a column in a `DataGridView` which includes before tax cash flow values.
Could someone please help me to calculate the IRR (Internal Rate of Return)?

Here is what I have done so far, but getting an error when trying to calculate the IRR function:

Error: Value of type 'Double' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Double. this error refers to "val" in the IRR function.

Thanks so much for your help! Please consider that, I am new and just start coding VB, thanks !!

```
Dim prec As String  "###,##0.00"
Dim guess As Double=0.1

For i =0 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count -1
For j =0 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count -1

Dim value(j) As Double
Dim val As Double
value(j) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value

value(j)=val
Dim cal As Double = IRR(val,guess) * 100

MsBox("IRR = " & Format(cal, CStr(prec)) & " % ")
Text1.Text=cal

Next
Next
```

Comment: You need two provide some more information to get a useful answer. Providing the code you have tried so far would be a good start.

Comment: thanks for the response, I just added my simple code...! I am not good at coding, so help or direction would be appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate solution:

```
Dim rowCount As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
Dim guess As Double = 0.1

Dim values(rowCount) As Double
For i As Integer = 0 To rowCount
values(i) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
Next
Dim cal As Double = IRR(values, guess) * 100
MsBox("IRR = " & Format(cal, CStr(prec)) & " % ")
Text1.Text=cal
```